# After function completes, redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of HTML which is unfortanetly an inherited onclick:

```
<a href="http:www.intendedlink.com" onclick="tracker(this, 'HondaAccord');return false;">Buy a Car</a>
```

What I would like is for the image to be generated onclick, appened to the div `car` and then transfered to the URL. As so:

```
function tracker(theLink, trackID) {
    var trackUrl = "http://www.mysite.com?something=" + trackID + "&val1&val2;";
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', trackUrl);
    img.appendTo('div.car');
    $(function () {=
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            var url = theLink;
            if (url) {
                window.location = theLink;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The image is generated but I'm never sent to the new link. Perhaps I don't even need to bind? But I want to be sure I'm not sent until the image is appended to `car` otherwise the tracking response is cut off prematurely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`theLink` is the anchor node, not it's href. try

```
window.location = theLink.href;
```

And, remove the click method, not needed. Instead, you need to wait until the image is loaded before you redirect to ensure that the request is sent.

```
function tracker(theLink, trackID) {
    var trackUrl = "http://www.mysite.com?something=" + trackID + "&val1&val2;";
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', trackUrl);
    //img.appendTo('div.car'); not needed
    img.load(function(){
      window.location = theLink.href;
    });    
}
```